# angularjs prevent controller from executing query before resolve

Tags: angularjs, authentication

i want to know if it's possible to do resolve using routeProvider before the controller calling any query.

here's the snippet of the code, it's modified from angular tutorial phonecat

```
PhoneCatApp.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider',
function($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $routeProvider.when('/phones', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller : 'PhoneListCtrl',
        resolve: {
            a: function($q,$location){
                var def = $q.defer();
                def.resolve('a');
                $location.path('/login');
                return def.promise;
            }
        }
    }).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'partials/login.html',
        controller : 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
                redirectTo : '/index';
        });
});
```

it's all working fine to redirect my route to /login, except that the controller still executes services from phoneServices that is Phone.query();

thanks in advance for your help :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

in your resolve property,

```
resolve: {
            a: function($q,$location){
                var def = $q.defer();
                def.resolve('a');
                $location.path('/login');
                return def.promise;
            }
        }
```

It shoud be something like:

```
 resolve: {
                    a: function($q,$location){
                        var def = $q.defer();

                        // process any ajax here
                        // then evaluate the response if success or fail 
                        if( requestIsSuccessful ) {
                           def.resolve('a');
                        } else {
                           def.reject();
                        }
                        return def.promise;
                    }
            }
```

def.reject() will terminate the process. You can make an HTTP Interceptor which listens to the status code returned and redirect to login page if status code is 401. You may also search for HTTP Interceptors.. it's on angularjs docs